# Best practices for photo storage

Tags: android, storage, photos

I want to make an Android application that has the same look as Instagram, which means every profile has a gallery of photos.

My question is about storing and retrieve those photos. I want to know what is the best practice for photo storage in a database (MySQL), more precisely:

- Should I store photos with original size (2mb for example) or resize them with smaller size?
- Should I store them with two version (smaller size photo, and normal size photo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving images in the database looks like overkill, it's not needed. **Saving on disk should be fine.**

Although **you should focus on your business logic** & leave this to image libraries which does this stuff & do best for memory & performance.

Some famous libs are:

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
- [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)
- & you will find many more

Almost each library does lots of stuff for you, such as:

- **In memory cache([LRU Cache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html))** - so that UI thread is not blocked from doing I/O
  operation from disks
- **Disk Cache** - To keep images saved for further
  app sessions, also when memory cache reaches its limit its have to be
  evicted from it., you can specify disk cache size.
- Various image scaling strategies
- Image transformations
- Clearing up bitmaps for freeing up memory
- Network operations on background threads
- Background threads management & **so on..**

My suggestion is to go with one of the image library

Comment: thanks for your answer its nice! but what about saving image, if i have image with big size sh?ould i resize it and save it with less size ?

Comment: because i made test for Facebook .. i tried to send image via Messenger with original size 2 mb, and after i download it from FB and i found size with just 700 ko

Comment: - There is no standard answer to this, you need to figure out what works best for you for your usecase.
- Glide offers different Disk caching strategies, you can save "original image", "scaled down image" based on your view size, "Final image" with all transformations, or cache all image variants.
- I am not sure about Facebook, it might be serving images based on device where it is serving image, try to download the same image on Desktop, you might get better resolution there

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the best practice is to store the photos in a database. 
In the DB you store the link/location of the photos example a url to a photo.
About smaller size photo it depends on what you are trying to accomplish  because now you need more space to pay for and maybe less bandwidth because you can put thumbnails and let it only load the original size when a user clicks on it. So it all depends what and how you want to archieve

Comment: yes so its good idea to save image with two version (normal size and thumbnail) ?

Comment: yes instead of loading the big images in a gallery , you load the thumbnails , which save you bandiwth and also load faster example if a user has 10 photos in his gallery and each photo is 3mb  everytime someone new open his gallery you use 30mb so if 10 people load his gallery you are already at 300mb , if you use thumbnails and each thumbnail is lets say 30kb  , with the same amount of people visiting you be sitting about  30*10 *10 =3000kb lets say 3mb .  but it depends on the size of the thumbnails they could be smaller or bigger

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for storing images is to simply cache them as files and not save them in a database. You could save them as blobs in an sql db but they should be less than 32px by 32px to make things smooth. Everything else should be saved as files. Let me give you an example of WhatsApp.
WhatApp caches most of it's images as files and only saves the pixelated thumbnail in a database.